# LINQ left outer join on date not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have this collection of `GroupedResult`

```
IQueryable<GroupedResult> groupedResult = from p in db.Departure
group p by new { p.Terminal, p.DepartureDate, p.DepartureDate.Month } into g
select new GroupedResult
{
  terminal = g.Key.Terminal.Code,
  date = g.Key.DepartureDate,
  distance = g.Count(),
  month = g.Key.Month
};
```

The problem is that the collection I get has some dates missing. For example db.Departure contains Feb. 1, 2, 4, and 6. I also wanted to show `GroupedResult` for Feb. 3 and 5 so I use the following code to create a collection of dates starting from a particular start date:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (var dt = date; dt <= DateTime.Now; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
    dates.Add(dt);
}
```

And then join `dates` with `groupedResult`

```
var result = from p in groupedResult.ToList()
from q in dates.Where(r => r == p.date).DefaultIfEmpty()
select p;
```

The result I get is same as the one with `groupedResult`. **How can I also show the entries with no date data?**

Comment: because you are doing select p

Comment: I think you have to create new anonymous class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are selecting P at the very end.....you have to create new anonymous class

```
var result = from q in dates
join p in groupedResult.ToList() on q equals p.date into joinedResult
from r in joinedResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
terminal = r==null?null:r.terminal,
  date = q,
  distance = r==null?null:r.distance,
  month = r==null?null:r.month
};
```

Comment: Using this I still get the same result.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with this syntax `join from q in dates...`

Comment: Yes I saw that, but the error says `Invalid expression term 'from'`. Is `join from q in dates` a valid syntax?

Comment: corrected that too....there was extra form clause....I have not tested it so there might be syntactical error....but your code should look something like that.....do let me know if it works....otherwise gimme some time then I will test it and give you correct code

Comment: `q` cant be accessed in `date = q.date` so I used `p.date` instead. Still, the same result.

Comment: I have update the code and have tested it as well and now it works

Comment: `p` doesnt exists in current context. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from p in groupedResult.ToList()
from q in dates.Where(r => r == p.date).DefaultIfEmpty()
select p;
```

You've got the left join the wrong way around. You're selecting all items from your `groupedResult` and then ask LINQ to get all dates - or none if there is none - that match a date that already exists in the `groupedResult`.

```
var result = from q in dates
             from p in groupedResult.Where(r => r.date == q).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { Date = q, Items = p };
```

This works, because you select all dates and search for matching grouped items instead.

Comment: I see. But I got function evaluation timeout after running this.